# There is no procedure with the name `apoc.periodic.iterate`

Tags: docker, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm running Neo4j (v 3.1.3) within a Docker (v17.05.0-ce-rc1) container on OSX (v10.11.6) and I've "installed" the APOC jar file, see:

```
$ docker exec -it sandbox-db ls /plugins
apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar
```

I also see the container is properly configured to pick up plugins from that location:

```
$ docker exec -it sandbox-db grep plugins conf/neo4j.conf
dbms.directories.plugins=/plugins
```

and I can see a reference in the logs to it:

```
$ docker exec -it sandbox-db grep apoc logs/debug.log
2017-04-26 17:26:13.744+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]  [classpath + loader.0] file:/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar
```

the complete logs: http://termbin.com/5i4q

yet, when I issue a call to an apoc procedure I get the following:

> There is no procedure with the name `apoc.periodic.iterate` registered
>   for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure
>   name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed

what does "properly deployed" mean? and what could be wrong?

Comment: can you add your original docker run command?

Comment: I followed [this link](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_apoc_with_neo4j_docker_image) from APOC docs and works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.  I figured it out.  there was a `apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar` file in the plugins/ directory but it did not contain a jar file!  I must have downloaded it with `curl` and it failed but instead of letting me know, it wrote an HTML file with the error.  grr...

did the download correctly and now everything works

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
cp apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar plugins/
docker run -v `pwd`:/data -v `pwd`/plugins:/plugins -p 7474:7474 neo4j:3.1.3
```

lists all apoc functions when I call `apoc.help("")` in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in 2022

To enable APOC functions for neo4j when you run it in a container, set the `NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS` env variable to `["apoc"]`. Take note the double quotes are part of the value, so you may need some escaping for them.

Example for `docker run`:

```
--env NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS='["apoc"]'
```

See https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/operations/#docker-neo4jlabs-pluginsneo4j.com